# Haskell database query inside ScottyM() function

Tags: sql, rest, haskell, scotty

I'm trying to write simple rest API. I use Database.SQLite.Simple, Scotty and Aeson. I have a problem with DB query inside ScottyM() route function. When I have something like this

```
routes :: [User] -> ScottyM ()
routes allUsers = do
    get "/users/:id" $ do
        id <- param "id"
        json ([x | x <- allUsers, userId x == id] !! 0)

main = do
    conn <- open "data.db"
    users <- ( query_ conn "select id, first_name, second_name, team from users" :: IO [User] )
    scotty 3000 (routes users)
```

everything works fine, but in this scenario allUsers will get updated only once at server start. I want to query every time anyone ask about it. So I wrote this:

```
routes :: Connection -> ScottyM ()
routes conn= do
   get "/users/:id" $ do
        id <- param "id"
        users <- ( query_ conn "select id, first_name, second_name, team from users" :: IO [User] )
        json (users !! id)

main = do
    conn <- open "data.db"
    scotty 3000 (routes conn)
```

I get error

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT
                                Text IO [a0]’
            with actual type ‘IO [User]’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  users <- (query_
              conn "select id, first_name, second_name, team from users" ::
              IO [User])
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘do { id <- param "id";
        users <- (query_
                    conn "select id, first_name, second_name, team from users" ::
                    IO [User]);
        json (users !! id) }’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  get "/users/:id"
  $ do { id <- param "id";
         users <- (query_
                     conn "select id, first_name, second_name, team from users" ::
                     IO [User]);
         json (users !! id) }
```

how to fix that? Also how can I pass arguments to sql query if I want for example `select * from users where id = id from parameters`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`get`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.0/docs/Web-Scotty.html#v:get) function's second argument is of type [`ActionM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.0/docs/Web-Scotty.html#t:ActionM). If you investigate further, you'll see this is just shorthand for the more complicated looking [`ActionT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.0/docs/Web-Scotty-Internal-Types.html#t:ActionT), with `e` as `Text` and `m` as `IO`.

Because your `do` block is of this type, you can't call `IO` functions directly. You need to use `liftIO` to get the right type. So just adding a `liftIO` before the `query_` call should fix it.

There's an example called [using scotty with IO](https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty/wiki) in the project wiki which shows this.